# Trailing underscore in `np.ix_`

Tags: python, numpy, naming-conventions

Why does the name of [`np.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) contain a trailing underscore?

Comment: According to PEP 8, a trailing underscore is used to avoid conflict with a python keyword (e.g. class_). But ix not a python keyword.

Comment: Perhaps this is in order to avoid conflicts with [pandas' `ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing-loc-iloc-and-ix)? However, as normally one uses namespaces, this is a weird reason.

Comment: @Bach - `numpy.ix_`, `numpy.r_`, etc predate `pandas` by more than a decade.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can't give a complete reason, but it's for symmetry with `np.r_`, `np.c_`, etc.  I can make a guess for the overall reason:

All of the short numpy operators like `np.r_`, `np.ix_`, etc are oriented towards interactive use.

Therefore, it's common (although not advisible) to do `from numpy import *` in an interactive console.

`r`, `c`, `ix`, etc, are likely to be variable names.  Therefore, they're probably suffixed with `_` to prevent getting clobbered when a user defines a variable named `r` or `ix` in an interactive session after doing `from numpy import *`.

Comment: This is very convincing.

Comment: All 4 are in 'numpy.lib.index_tricks'.  `np.ix_` has a conventional function definition.  But the related `np.r_` is not, strictly speaking, a function.  It uses indexing syntax.  All have to do with constructing grids.

Answer (score 2):

`ix_` is found in `numpy.lib.index_tricks`

This module is attributed to:

```
# Written by Konrad Hinsen <hinsen@cnrs-orleans.fr>
# last revision: 1999-7-23
#
# Cosmetic changes by T. Oliphant 2001
```

It was write many years ago, and incorporated as legacy component in the current `numpy`.  The names were chosen by one programmer many years ago, and never changed to fit Python community standards.

From the `.ix_` doc:

> Using `ix_` one can quickly construct index arrays that will index
>       the cross product.

My guess: 'i' for 'index', 'x' for 'cross', '_' to avoid confusion with a (potentially) common indexing variable name.

Similarly named objects from the same module are `r_`, `c_` and `s_`.  Technically they are not functions, since they are not callable (don't take `()`).  But they are indexable (take `[]`). They are actually instances of classes that have `__getitem__` definitions. `ogrid` and `mgrid` are also indexable objects.

Comment: This is a bit off topic, but anyway: if `.ix_` is a legacy component, is there a different, currently preferred way to do the same job?

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924303/numpy-mutidimensional-subsetting/21924870#21924870 show several ways of doing the same thing, one using `ix_`.  Maybe 'legacy' was the wrong term.  It's a useful (but not core) simple function, with an idiosyncratic name.  You'd have to search the repository to know if anyone wants to rename or replace it.